# Export-SPWeb List with spaces in list name

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I am trying to backup a list and am getting the error

> Export-SPWeb : Cannot find an SPWeb object with Id or Url

.  I'm guessing this is related to the space in the list name.  I've tried this command a million different ways, so what is the best way to do this?  I've read about the double quotes, but can't make it work.

Export-SPWeb -Identity https://servername/path -Path C:\backup.cmp -ItemUrl "/Lists/Mortgage Referrals"

Comment: i am sure you have access to central admin, try to export from central admin

Comment: I'm guessing because your -ItemUrl isn't valid. Export-SPWeb -ItemUrl states "Specifies the URL of the Web application, GUID, or object to be exported. The type must be a valid URL; for example, http://server_name."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You command should be look like this

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity https://servername/path -Path C:\backup.cmp -ItemUrl "Lists/Mortgage Referrals"
```

- in identity complete URL of Site collection.
- at ItemURL you should not use '/' if it is on root of site collection.

Comment: That was it!  After the -ItemUrl I had: "/lists/etc" instead of your "lists/etc".  Can't believe I missed it.  Thanks!

Comment: i am sure, you will marked it answer n vote up as well.:)

Comment: Are you sure that it needs `/` if not at root of site collection? I thought `ItemUrl` was web-relative (I could be well wrong)

Comment: @JamesLove Citing Brian from MS PFE team (link is up there in my answer): *basically under the covers the Export-SPWeb cmdlet will call SPWeb.GetList(), but prior to calling that function it will prepend the SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl and an extra “/” if the string in ItemUrl does not have a leading “/”. In short, to be safe if you always set the ItemUrl parameter to the server relative url and then path to the list, it should always work regardless of web location*

Answer (score 1):

General syntax is this:

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity "http://site" -Path D:\list.cmp -ItemUrl "/Lists/{ListUrl}"
```

But what you need to put in `{List}` part of `-ItemUrl` argument is a **URL, not a list title**. To find it, look at URL of any *view* of your list, 'Mortgage Referrals'. It looks like `http://site/Lists/{ListUrl}/view.aspx`. That's it. Copy that part to `Export-SPWeb`.

Get it in powershell:

```
($w.Lists["Mortgage Referrals"].DefaultViewUrl -split "/")[2]
# this will return {ListUrl} part
```

So, combined two-liner looks like this:

```
$itemUrl = (((Get-SPWeb "http://site").Lists["Mortgage Referrals"].DefaultViewUrl -split "/") | select -first 3) -join "/"
Export-SPWeb -Identity "http://site" -Path D:\list.cmp -ItemUrl $itemUrl
```

---

Update: oh, just one more thing here. `Export-SPWeb` differs when executed on root sites and non-root sites. Take a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/briangre/archive/2014/03/18/export-spweb-syntax-changes-between-root-site-and-sub-sites.aspx